# Debug Warnings in VSCode

Tags: debugging, vs-code, debug

A coworker gets warnings while editing JS files (e.g. misspelling variable names, missing semicolons, missing closing brackets or parentheses...).  That doesn't happen on my VSCode.  I don't see errors until I try to deploy to the server.

How can I get this functionality turned on?

Tom

Comment: They might have Prettier or some other formatter enabled.  Disable it or adjust the settings in those config files

Comment: They may have this installed: https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc or they might be using jshint